# Attribute changes with MutationObserver only found if code is inside a loop

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mutation-observers

I am having some trouble detecting attribute changes of an html element with js and `MutationObserver`. This is the code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  const checkForLoading = setInterval(function () {

    let loading = document.getElementById("sequence");

    if (loading) {
        console.log("loading detected");

        const loadingObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
          console.log("mutation detected");
          if (loading.getAttribute('data-dash-is-loading') === 'true') {
            console.log("loading");
            // loading.style.visibility = 'hidden';
          } else {
            console.log("not loading");
            // loading.style.visibility = 'visible';
          }
        });

        const observerOptions = {
          attributes: true,
        }

        loadingObserver.observe(loading, observerOptions);
        clearInterval(checkForLoading);
    }
  }, 100);
});
```

Because the element is not available immediately I have the `checkForLoading` loop set up. The attribute `'data-dash-is-loading'` is only set when an element is loading and otherwise not available. This code only works if the loop keeps on running after the sequence element is detected and `clearInterval(checkForLoading)` is not called. However I would like to avoid running this loop constantly. Any help to fix this issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually means the element is recreated, so you need to observe its ancestor higher up the DOM tree and add `subtree: true`.

For example, a parent element:

```js
loadingObserver.observe(loading.parentElement, {attributes: true, subtree: true});
```

If this doesn't help at once you can try `document.body` first to make sure the mutation actually happens, then try various ancestor elements in-between to find the one that stays the same.

In the callback you'll need to verify that the mutation occurred on your desired element:

```js
for (const m of mutations) {
  if (m.target.id === 'foo') {
    // it's the desired element, do something about it here and stop the loop
    break;
  }
}
```